# Wi-Fi hotspot traffic while connected to PIA VPN

Tags: wifi-hotspot, vpn, wifi-tethering, 7.1-nougat

### **Background**

Android 7.1.1 Nexus 6P uses VPN app from Private Internet Access.  The app has a "Per App Setting" that allows certain apps to bypass the VPN connection (some games like Pokemon Go don't operate if behind a VPN, you get an 'unable to authenticate' error until you disable VPN or turn off PG in the per app settings).

My son has my old Moto X phone (no SIM card) and needs to be tethered to my phone to have Wi-Fi when we're out and about. He does not have the PIA app installed on his phone.

### **PROBLEM**

When he plays his Pokemon Go game, and we are tethered while my VPN app is operating, he cannot log in or authenticate with his game on his phone. I'll need to turn off my VPN completely before his app will allow him to log and play.

### **QUESTION**

Is there an Android System Process that I can allow to bypass the VPN so that his tethered Wi-Fi connection isn't blocked?

Comment: I have exactly the same setup as you by the sounds of things. However I've never had the requirement you have so I've never noticed. I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but one option you do have is to use a third party hotspot app then I guess you will be able to bypass using the per app settings. Additionally, I'd get on the PIA forums. The devs seem pretty open to suggestions and recommendation from what I've experienced

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Use of VPN/GPS spoofing is prohibited while using Pokémon Go. Also, your virtual location may coincide with your actual location, making Niantic think your phone is spoofed. That's why it may not allow access till you disable VPN.

You can allow Tethering and portable hotspot app from PIA setting , that will do the job.

Comment: If his son downloads the VPN app it will make no difference as he is connected to a hotspot with a VPN IP. You have asked the OP to check if you can bypass the hotspot process in the PIA app... that was the OPs question, you have just repeated it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to use if you are **rooted**:

Since your son is connecting to tethering through VPN traffic, you can forward all data traffic through the VPN to allow connectivity.

You need to type the following in terminal **as su**:

```
iptables -t filter -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

This will allow  fowarding of traffic through VPN and you son will be able to authenticate. Otherwise you could try a 3rd party app to tether and see if it resolves

Comment: no, i am not rooted and dont plan on rooting.